# Importing data from Access to SQL Server (with minor table changes)

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, import

I'm currently working on migrating an application from MS-Access to MS SQL Server.  In the process, there are a few minor changes that I am making to the table layouts (I am splitting a few things up into more two tables), however, I would still like to keep all the data that is present in the database.

What would be the best way to import the data, while changing the database structure to suit my new requirements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are planning to upgrade a Microsoft Access database to SQL Server 2008, use the SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) rather than the upsizing wizard built into MS Access.

Download from here (Thanks Tony): [SQL Server Migration Assistant 2008 for Access](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28763)

Comment: Latest version available from: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=133B59C2-C89C-4641-BEBB-6D04476EC1BA&displaylang=en

Comment: Amazing find. Much better than the Access tools, especially when you have a column named `Collate` that the upsizing tool chokes on.

Answer (score 2):

use the **upsize wizard** in Access to move all your tables and data into SQL Server and then do you table changes there

Comment: The upsizing wizard is always behind SQL Server versions, so the SSMA is almost always a better choice.